# React hide element that is over the height

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I remove the div that is being overlapped of the given height.

```html
<div style={{height: 100}}>
<div style={{height: 50}}>first content</div>
<div style={{height: 50}}>secondcontent</div>
<div style={{height: 50}}>third content</div>
</div>
```

I would like the remove the "third content" div in the DOM.

The data are dynamically rendered and I dont have a control of the data.
So the FrontEnd will hide the extra data to avoid being script.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not just not rendering it? We need a little more context to this

Comment: Please show us the full component

Comment: @sinned do you have Html access for your parent div...Then maybey you  could remove the 3rd element

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. Already solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style={{height: 100, overflow: "hidden"}}>
    <div style={{height: 50}}>first content</div>
    <div style={{height: 50}}>secondcontent</div>
    <div style={{height: 50}}>third content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this will just hide it, i would like to totally remove it in the dom

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a conditional rendering case:

Considering your parent has a height: 100px- logic will be something like:
if innerElements height is less than 100- keep rendering items.